# Sum of one columns based on values in another column

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am creating a macro that sum the values in Column B with an offset of (0, -1) until the value in column A changes. The summed number will output on the last row in column C. In the example, Column B sums (4+6+1+7+4+4) from B2-B7 and outputs that value in C7. Then the value in Column A changes to 'Susan" and it sums B8-B12 and out puts that value in C12.

Any advice for how to set this up?

[image: Example of Spreadsheet]

Currently, I'm using =SUMIF(B:B, "Joe", C:C) 
But in my spreadsheet, Joe comes up again, but I don't want his later values added to the first sum.

I could go apply a simpler SUM function, but there are over 2000 values and the number of values each time the same name comes up changes. In the full version there are more columns like Dates, Info, etc., but the name is the only identifier I'd have to go by.

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2odGT.png)

Comment: Can you post the code you've attempted so we can see where you need help specifically?

Comment: use the formula `=SUMIF(A:A,A:A,B:B)` in column C.

Comment: For VBA have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.SumIf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumif).

Comment: You could pivot the data and aggregate the values, use subtotals from the Data/Outline Ribbon command, use a `SUMIF`  formula in column C... and there are probably another 3 or 4 ways to achieve the desired figures without writing a single line of code. Why use any VBA at all then? If it's for learning purposes, then fine - but then, you should be posting the code you have and describe a specific problem with it; are you familiar with `For` loops? Declaring variables? Accessing `Range` values? We could give you code, but we don't know what you already know... help us help you! =)

Answer (score 2):

In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A2=A3,"",SUM($B$1:B2)-SUM($C$1:C1))
```

and copy downward:

[image]

We add the values in column **B**, but remove values already captured for previous names.

Comment: This is nice and simple and will achieve what you require